# Gradient runs out when I resize my window

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS gradient that runs the height of the page:

```
html {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e5fcc2), color-stop(47%,#ecfdd2), color-stop(100%,#fafef3));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#e5fcc2, #fafef3);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Yet for some reason, when I resize my window, specifically when I make it smaller, there is a large white area at the bottom of the page where the gradient runts out. When the window is long, I don't have this problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you must specify for what browser you have that problem. Also the version is important. For example chrome 10+ uses another gradient command then chrome <10

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't reproduce this on chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/RCrZQ/

Comment: Using Chrome 21 but things are fine in Safari 6. This also occurs in FF 12, what do I need to add to that code for this not to happen? `fixed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

Needed to set `min-height: 100%` which worked across Chrome 21, FF 12 and Safari 6. 
I also had `background-repeat: no-repeat;` in the `html` block.